# Not found 404 while accessing WCF Rest service (WebGet) when url segment is json string

Tags: c#, json, wcf, wcf-rest

In my project i have to pass dynamic Json string to WCF Rest service web get.

when i pass some string as below everything works fine.

http://localhost:58014/MyService.svc/api/queries/somestirng

but when i pass json string as url segment not found error occurs.

{"Key":"UserHomePageInfoQuery","Message":"{\"UserName\":\"usr83\"}"}

http://localhost:58014/MyService.svc/api/queries/257b%2522Key%2522%253a%2522UserHomePageInfoQuery%2522%252c%2522Message%2522%253a%2522%257b%255c%2522UserName%255c%2522%253a%255c%2522usr83%255c%2522%257d%2522%257d

Here is my service operation contract definition

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "api/queries/{queryString}",                        
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    Response Query(string queryString);
```

I know i can use POST, but all requests to service is query

I have another service for commands by POST

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "api/commands/",
            Method = "POST",            
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]       
        Response Execute(Request request)
```

Comment: Does it necessarily have to be a GET? You could simply POST the JSON string.

Comment: Yes because only query operations are passing thrugh this servis. i have another service for commands as post

Comment: Isn't it possible to change `WebGet` to `WebInvoke`, too? Or is it a requirement, that this method should only accept GETs?

Comment: Yes. It shoul only accept GETs. I edit question for clearity

Comment: Have you checked this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551412/passing-json-objects-in-a-rest-http-get-request-using-spring-mvc

Comment: can you post your configuration file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a wildcard (*) in the {queryString} parameter, which means "the rest of the URI"

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675245.aspx

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "api/queries/{*queryString}",                        
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    Response Query(string queryString);
```